# Timeout ao tentar utilizar o Composer

Tags: linux, composer

Quando eu estou rodando o comando `composer ìnstall` ou `composer update`, estou recebendo essa mensagem depois de um certo tempo de espera:

> The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be
>   downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
>   https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information
>   was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date

Já verifiquei a conexão com a internet e está tudo certo (já que até a pergunta consegui postar aqui :p).

O estranho é que, quando conecto no meu servidor na Amazon e rodo os mesmos comandos, a instalação ocorre normalmente.

Alguém sabe por que o Composer retorna essa mensagem?

Há alguma configuração que eu posso usar pra resolver isso?

**Atualização 1**

Quando rodo o comando `wget https://getcomposer.org/versions`, também estou tendo problemas com timeout.

**Atualização 2**:

Tentei remover o composer e instalar de novo. Usei o comando `curl -sS http://getcomposer.org/installer | php`

O erro retornado é:

> The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded:
>   failed to open stream: Connection timed out Retrying..

**Atualização 3**:

Ao tentar rodar o comando `composer self-update -vvv`, recebo o seguinte log:

```
Loading config file /home/wallace/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /home/wallace/.composer/auth.json
Reading /home/wallace/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /home/wallace/.composer/config.json
Loading config file /home/wallace/.composer/auth.json
Loading config file /home/wallace/.composer/composer.json
Loading config file /home/wallace/.composer/auth.json
Reading /home/wallace/.composer/auth.json
Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: valid
Executing command (/home/wallace/.composer): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v
Executing command (/home/wallace/.composer): git describe --exact-match --tags
Executing command (/home/wallace/.composer): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD
Reading /home/wallace/.composer/vendor/composer/installed.json
Running 1.3.1 (2017-01-07 18:08:51) with PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 on Linux / 4.4.0-57-generic
Downloading https://getcomposer.org/versions

[Composer\Downloader\TransportException]                                     
The "https://getcomposer.org/versions" file could not be downloaded: failed  
to open stream: Connection timed out
```

Comment: Teste o comando `composer diagnose` (ou `php composer.phar diagnose`).

Comment: Removi o composer e não estou conseguindo instalar :\

Comment: Checa o firewall sob o IPV6 e o IPV4.

Comment: Como assim firewall? falou grego agora, kkkkkk

Comment: Ué kkkk, porque grego? O Ubuntu não tem interface de Firewall em GUI?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento nunca vi, kkkkkkk

Comment: Wallace, antes de mais nada, em outro computador na mesma rede, você consegue instalar o composer?

Comment: Vou ver no notebook do outro programador aqui, pera ae

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento no computador do outro cara aqui funcionou.

Comment: Blz um problema a menos, então provavelmente é a sua maquina, agora se puder confirmar a versão do PHP usado no CLI e se os certificados SSL estão ok, podemos fazer outros testes.

Comment: Desliga os torrents.

Comment: @Zooboomafoo quem dera fosse só isso, kkkkkkkk

Comment: Já aconteceu isso comigo. Mas eu insistia e funcionava. Já tentou usar o `sudo` antes do comando ?

Comment: Ou é o `max_execution_time` do PHP que está pouco para o tempo da requisição.

Comment: Pode rodar tambpem `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @Zooboomafoo na verdade, os comandos do  `composer` funcionam normalmente, exceto os que usam conexão com a internet.

Comment: Sim. O `composer` tem um bug e as vezes tem que fazer o `dump-autoload`. Mas ele não é nada além do que códigos PHP, então talvez precise alterar o `max_execution_time` do `php.ini`.

Comment: Eu consigo resolver o problema se eu desconectar a internet e conectar de novo. Mas quando passa um tempo, o problema volta a aparecer. Parece que é algum problema realmente na rede.

Comment: Estou tendo esse problema no Windows, a diferença é que acontece tanto no PHP quanto o Composer. E, **mesmo desativando o IPv6**, o problema persiste.

Comment: @CypherPotato tenta colocar o DNS da Google. Configura como `8.8.8.8` e `8.8.4.4`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters resolvi setando o `default_socket_timeout` do **php.ini** para `9999`. Se colocar `0`, o timeout será realmente zero e não infinito.

Comment: Saudações, seu que a dúvida é meio antiga mas eu estava tendo esse problema nas últimas semanas... Era o IPv6, desabilitei e funcionou. Desabilitei na interface gráfica do Gnome e estou usando o Ubuntu 20, era uma conexão wi-fi.
Depois de tantas tentativas cheguei até aqui: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md Não foi exatamente fazendo como diz no link acima que resolvi mas deu uma luz...

Answer (score 0):

Olá hoje (08/12/2020) enfrentei o mesmo problema e consegui seguindo esta sugestão do [Pablo Palacios](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4584038/pablo-palacios); https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737389/connection-timeout-error-while-updating-composer-on-digital-ocean

Ele falou para executar o comando abaixo como root para tornar o IPV4 mais anterior do que o IPV6:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100' >> /etc/gai.conf"
```

depois rodei o `composer diagnose` e passou sem erro e consegui baixar os acotes que precisava.